# fatal: "SHA" matching multiple patchsets during build process in jenkins and using gerrit version 2.16 how to solve this

Tags: sha

During build process jenkins gives -1 to code and returns following error

Fatal:"xxxxxx"matching multiple patchsets

using gerrit version 2.16 the same SHA is associated with multiple patchsets how to overcome this error as jenkins gives -1 during build